# Simplify POST request in Spring-Data-JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Currently writing a food management system using `REST API`, `Spring boot`, `data-jpa`, `security` and `mysql`.

I have entity classes `Product` and `Category` and they have one-to-many relationship between them. Everything works fine, however since in `Product` class I have category field with `Category` type, I have to enter entire category object in `POST` method (`/products/add`).My question is how can I make it possible to enter only `categoryId` in order to create new Product entity in database. If I use `DTO`, by only sending categoryId, will it fill `categoryName` field also? (because If I don't manually, category appears null).

```
@Data
@Embeddable
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer productId;
    private String productName;
    private double price;
    private String filePath;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="category_id")
    private Category category;
    
}
```

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer categoryId;
    private String categoryName;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    private List<Product> productList;

}
```

[image]

[image]

I tried different `cascade` and `fetching` types and got so many errors with some of them. Still the same situation. To my mind, there should be a way to achieve this over modifying relationships between entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update : Solution. Need to use  DTO with ModelMapper . In ProductDto create field name with categoryName. But it should be same with categoryName field in Category entity class. ModelMapper will automatically map these to fields. So I can get and add only categoryName without filling whole Category object.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to populate the Category while persisting the Product and neither you need to fetch it using select before persisting the product.
*You can get a reference of the category and provide it in the Product entity and persist it.*
Also, i would suggest to define the fetching strategy for the `@ManyToOne as Lazy`

```
Category category = categoryRepository.getReferenceById(1L);

productRepository.save(
    new Product()
        .setId(1L)
        .setProductName("Soul stone")
        .setCategory(category)
);
```

Comment: Well, thanks for advice, but I already tried FetchType Lazy, my problem is when I want to call add method, I need to give category object . But in postman or swagger I have to enter entire category object ( as you did above example). To my mind, it doesn't make sense since I want to enter only categoryId field.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have to create product categories in database with different IDs. When you post a product you have to show categoryId in Json file. After create a repository class for   findById If categories are not exist you cannot do it. So, after adding Categories in new database you can post your products by sending only id of category like. By the way try to send DTO not an entity.

```
{
    "productName": "product01",
    "price": 24.6,
    "filePath": ----,
    "category": 2 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for information. I already had done those beforehand. ModelMapper saved me from situation.